# build in Maven 2.2.1 with JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7 what changes are needed in pom.xml

Tags: build, compilation, maven-2, java-7, java-6

While building the project in Maven 2.2.1 as some of my projects are in JDK1.6 and some in JDK 1.7.I need to build the entire modules.
What are the changes shall I need to make as I am getting the below error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
```

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

abc\TestSerializeUtil.java:[54,61] [unchecked] unchecked conversion

could not parse error message:   required: Map
  found:    Map
abc\TestSerializeUtil.java:93: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
       Map mapResult = SerializeUtil.fromXML(xml, Map.class, classLoader);
                                                             ^

Comment: Which maven-compiler-plugin version do you use?

Comment: Apache Maven 2.2.1 on Windows 7

Comment: I didn't ask for the Maven version (mentioned in the headline). I asked for the maven-compiler-plugin version? Cause you didn't post the full output.

Comment: <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.3</version>